# Trying to manually reorder a bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I need this chart to show the bars in a different order.

[image]

The "pretest" bar needs to be first. Nothing happens other than my labels changing.  Would really appreciate some help!

This research only makes sense if the table is in the correct order.

I have been using this code trying to change the order.

```
plot_data2 <- main_data %>%
  dplyr::select(training_type,
                pretest_result,
                C1_reps,
                C2_reps,
                P1_reps,
                P2_reps) %>%
  drop_na(pretest_result) %>%
  gather(test, reps, pretest_result, C1_reps, C2_reps, P1_reps, P2_reps) %>%
  group_by(test, training_type) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(reps),
    lci = t.test(reps)$conf.int[[1]],
    uci = t.test(reps)$conf.int[[2]]
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
mutate(test = factor(
  test,
  levels = c("pretest_result", "C1_reps", "C2_reps", "P1_reps", "P2_reps")
))
```

This is my code for the plot.

```
ggplot(plot_data2, aes(x=test, y = mean, fill = training_type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lci, ymax=uci),
                  width=.2,                    
                  position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(5,1,2,3,4)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Pretest", "C1", "C2", "P1", "P2")) +
  labs(x = "Test type", y = "Average repitions", fill = "Training type") +
  theme_bw()
```

This is my data

```
main_data <- structure(
  list(
    Horse = c("Skori", "Raudhetta", "Emma", "Freyr", 
 "Nick", "Hilda", "Aleiga", "Sinfonia", "Saga", "Fengur", "Herkules", 
 "Rumur", "Gaia", "Frøya", "Fanta", "Lindus", "Betty", "Sjamina", 
 "Dimma", "Astrix", "Presley", "Odin", "Poineten", "Gåte", "Skori", 
 "Raudhetta", "Emma", "Freyr", "Nick", "Hilda", "Aleiga", "Sinfonia", 
 "Saga", "Fengur", "Herkules", "Rumur", "Gaia", "Frøya", "Fanta", 
 "Lindus", "Betty", "Sjamina", "Dimma", "Astrix", "Presley", "Odin", 
 "Poineten", "Gåte"), 
 C1_reps = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 
4, 4, 5, 4, 5), 
C2_reps = c(5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5), 
Compliance = c(3, 
4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 3, 4, 3), 
P1_reps = c(5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 
0, 4, 6, 3, 6, 7, 0, 7, 4, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), 
P2_reps = c(NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 6, 2, 6, 7, 4, 
 6, 5, 6, 4, 4, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0), 
Test.group = c(1, 1, 
 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
 3, 3, 3, 3), 
training_type = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", 
"PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "TT", "TT", "TT", 
"TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", 
"TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT", "TT"), 
pretest_result = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0, 0, 3, 5, 4, 2, 9, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4, 6, 
6, 16, 0) 
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

Comment: I think there are pipes (%>%) missing between the `summarize`, `ungroup` and `mutate`. Also please add some example data, for example run `dput(head(main_data, 150))`, and copy the output it creates from the R console and paste it into a code chunk in your question, in order to share the first 150 rows of your data with us.

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the question text and add the data

Comment: Also updated the code

Comment: There were still some pipes issues and also the data wasn't working for me. I fixed those issues and submitted an edit for your question. Went to try the code after that and it seems to produce your intended output.

Comment: Oh, my god.  With your edits, it finally worked.  I have spent INORDINATE amounts of time on this.  Now i can finally write my discussion!!  Thanks so much!

Comment: That happens to me sometimes as well! You basically had everything right, just some syntax issues. Good luck with the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

Bar order is determined by order of factor levels. To reorder bars, you need to reorder factor levels by adding something like the following after your first call to mutate(). List the levels of your factor in the order you want your bars to appear

```
mutate(test = forcats::fct_relevel(test, "pretest_result", "C1_reps", "C2_reps", "P1_reps", "P2_reps"))
```

Answer (score 0):

add `ordered = T` parameter to your script

...
mutate(test = factor(
  test,
  levels = c("pretest_result", "C1_reps", "C2_reps", "P1_reps", "P2_reps")
)
...

...
mutate(test = factor(
  test,
  levels = c("pretest_result", "C1_reps", "C2_reps", "P1_reps", "P2_reps"), **ordered = T**
)